# How to completely uninstal HPLIP

Tags: directory, printer, uninstall, hp, hp-printer

I have this annoying popup every time I start my pc and I don't know how to eliminate it and either the HPLIP.

[image]

I tried this method without success https://askubuntu.com/questions/1056077/how-to-install-latest-hplip-on-my-ubuntu-to-support-my-hp-printer-and-or-scanner

```
sh hplip-3.20.9.run --noexec
cd hplip-3.20.9
sudo python3 ./uninstall.py
sudo rm -rf /usr/share/hplip/
```

Maybe I'm not getting the directory correctly, I am not sure

Comment: Add the output of `dpkg-query -l | grep hplip` to your question.

Comment: I did this years ago, not sure if still correct. open up the "startup applications" editor from the admin menu.
add a new program, for the command put:
sleep 10;/usr/bin/hp-systray